# Python 3 and Excel, Finding complex module to use

Tags: python, excel, module

I've been looking for ages to find a suitable module to interact with excel, which needs to do the following:

1. Check a column of cells for an "incorrect" value and change it
2. Check for empty cells, and if so, replace it
3. Check a cell value is consistent with the contents of another cell(for example, if called Datasheet, the code in another cell = DS)and if not, change it.

I've looked at openpxyl but I am running Python 3 and I can only seem to find it working for 2.

I've seen a few others but they seem to be mainly focusing creating a new spreadsheet and simple writing/reading.

Comment: `openpyxl` definitely works with Python 3. But if your system has both versions of Python installed (which can easily happen without your realizing it) it is possible that `openpyxl` is only *installed* in your Python 2 environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pandas library is amazing to work with excel files. It can read excel files easily and you then have access to a lot of tools. You can do all the operations you mentionned above. You can also save your result in the excel format